Identify film about a strange road
I'm searching for a film about a strange road which doesn't appear on maps. The protagonist is a boy who works in a office (if I remember well). He goes to the road and pass a village where all took drugs. I think it's from USA, between 2000 and 2010.
The genre was strange as the movie but it was realistic with fantasy items. "Where all took drugs" Yes, when the protagonist enters the village only young people took drugs but then the fathers started to take drugs. I think that drugs were in a stick (maybe called euphoria?)

What was the genre? The other characters? The plot? And can you please elaborate on "where all took drugs"? (Do you mean the villagers? What kind of drugs? How was this depicted?)

The genre was strange as the movie but it was realist with fantasy items. "Where all took drugs" Yes, when the protagonist enter the village only young people took drugs but then the fathers started to took drugs. I think that drugs were in a stick (maybe called euphoria?)

Ah, OK. Much clearer.

I think you're after Interstate 60 from 2002 with James Marsden:

A confused young man (Marsden) takes a journey on a road that doesn't exist on any map.

He comes across a town where everyone is hooked on a drug called Euphoria. Here's the trailer:



